# GetEntryAssembly returns null...how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, vb6, assemblies

I have a WPF application that uses a third-party library to perform a specific task; this library, in one of its methods, executes the statement `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`.

If I run the WPF application on debug (by running a .Net exe for testing) the library works properly and `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns a reference to the assembly of the executable, but in production I have a different situation that causes me some problems.

In production, the WPF application is integrated with a VB6 application and programs are launched from a VB6 menu using the `InteropFormLibrary`; in this situation the library raise an exception because `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns `null` (it can't find the executable associated with the assembly).

My problem is that I can't change the code of the library because I don't have the sources available and I found the statement that throws the exception by `dll` decompiler and analyzing the method that was in the exception.

Now my question is: Is there any way to make sure that the method `GetEntryAssembly` doesn't return `null`? Can I assign or "circumvent" in some way?

Comment: Is it possible to execute the WPF application within a new AppDomain?

Comment: I'm trying but there are some problems with the interop

Comment: The cleanest way is to contact the library developer as the MSDN states the fact that `GetEntryAssembly` returns `null` if called from unmanaged code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need an alternative to \`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()\` that never returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165785/i-need-an-alternative-to-assembly-getentryassembly-that-never-returns-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be getting the developer of the dll to fix his code to support being hosted in a native (like VB6 or C/C++) process.

That said, if its not possible, you can try to host your .NET side in a separate process, being based on a .NET exe. Since you are doing VB6 interop you'll probably already be using COM interop, so you could just switch to the out-of-process COM model. This way your .NET components can run inside a .NET exe and have an entry point assembly. I've already done that for similar reasons and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes...it seems the only solution, now I'm trying to contact the library developers to fix the issue

Comment: Another "temporary" and "dangerous" solution that I found is use MSIL disassembler (from prompt using ildasm command) to modify statement and then recompile dll (using ilasm command). It works, but it isn't the best choice.

Comment: In general it doesn't work that easily because you lose the strong name of the assembly, causing you to recompile anyone who references that assembly, possibly causing a huge chain reaction.

Comment: Right...in fact I had to use "Strong Name Tool" to disable validation for dll (sn.exe -Vr) and this is not very safe.