# I need an alternative to `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` that never returns null

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection, entry-point

I need to find the assembly in which managed code execution started.

```
// using System.Reflection;
Assembly entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
```

This seems like the way to go, but the [MSDN reference page for `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) states that this method *"[c]an return null when called from unmanaged code."*

In that case, I would like to know which assembly was called by unmanaged code.

Is there a reliable way of doing this, i.e. one that always returns a non-null `Assembly` reference?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best I could think of so far is the following, which should work in a single-threaded scenario:

```
// using System.Diagnostics;
// using System.Linq; 
Assembly entryAssembly = new StackTrace().GetFrames().Last().GetMethod().Module.Assembly;
```

(The above snippet is optimized for ease of understanding, not for execution speed or memory efficiency.)

Comment: Upvoted, but would probably be better to do something like `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? new StackTrace().GetFrames().Last().GetMethod().Module.Assembly`

Comment: mscorelib... I would avoid this.

Answer (score 12):

I tried both methods of stakx.

[Method based on MainModule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14166515/249742) does not work in some special cases (dynamic assemblies for example).

[Method based on StackTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165787/249742) can return an assembly too high (or low) in the hierarchy, like mscorlib.

I made a little variant which works well in my use cases :

```
// using System.Diagnostics;
// using System.Linq;
var methodFrames = new StackTrace().GetFrames().Select(t => t?.GetMethod()).ToArray();
MethodBase entryMethod = null;
int firstInvokeMethod = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < methodFrames.Length; i++)
{
    var method = methodFrames[i] as MethodInfo;
    if (method == null)
        continue;
    if (method.IsStatic &&
        method.Name == "Main" &&
        (
            method.ReturnType == typeof(void) || 
            method.ReturnType == typeof(int) ||
            method.ReturnType == typeof(Task) ||
            method.ReturnType == typeof(Task<int>)
        ))
    {
        entryMethod = method;
    }
    else if (firstInvokeMethod == 0 &&
        method.IsStatic &&
        method.Name == "InvokeMethod" &&
        method.DeclaringType == typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle))
    {
        firstInvokeMethod = i;
    }
}

if (entryMethod == null)
    entryMethod = firstInvokeMethod != 0 ? methodFrames[firstInvokeMethod - 1] : methodFrames.LastOrDefault();

Assembly entryAssembly = entryMethod?.Module?.Assembly;
```

Basically, I walk the stack up until I find a [conventional method](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) named "Main" with `void` or `int` return type.
If no such method is found, I look for a method invoked via reflection. For example, NUnit uses that invocation to load unit tests.

Of course, I do that only if `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` returns `null`.

Comment: Main might return an `int` and there may be other Main methods in other classes, but a good start.

Comment: Correct, I updated my answer to reflect your suggestion for the return type (void, int, Task, Task<int>). As for an homonym "Main" method, I suppose that it is a rare case, and the code above is only a best effort, not a guarantee. Also, I take into account not only the name of the method but the stacktrace. So an other method "Main" declared in a library is not sufficient to deceive that snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Another (largely untested) starting point for a working solution might be something like this:

```
// using System;
// using System.Diagnostics;
// using System.Linq;
ProcessModule mainModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
Assembly entryAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                         .Single(assembly => assembly.Location == mainModule.FileName);
```

Some uncertainties remain:

- Modules and assemblies are not the same thing. `ProcessModule` might even be conceptually different from `Module`. Would the above code always work in the presence of multi-module (i.e. multi-file) assemblies, especially when an assembly's entry point is not in the manifest module?
- Is `Process.MainModule` guaranteed to always returns a non-null reference?